# Armazenar dados do usuário após login AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, front-end

Estou fazendo login através de uma requisição AJAX normalmente usando o $http, logo após o login, meu webservice retorna o ID do usuário que logou, então eu faço outra requisição para pegar esse usuário.

Com os dados desse usuário eu armazeno o ID e Name do usuário.

```
localStorageService.set('first_name',user.user_first_name);
localStorageService.set('id',user.user_id);
```

E algumas linhas acima eu coloco o nome do usuário numa variável $scope:

```
$scope.first_name = localStorageService.get('first_name');
```

Mas o meu grande problema é, logo após o login eu redireciono o usuário para a home ('/') do meu sistema e lá eu quero exibir uma mensagem: 'Olá Fulano' (nome do usuário). Mas o problema é que vem sem o nome do usuário, mas eu clicando em qualquer outra rota, por exemplo: ('/painel'), o nome é atualizado no headere aí ele aparece como eu gostaria.

Creio que devo estar me perdendo durante o loading da aplicação.

Resumindo: se existir outra maneira melhor de fazer isso eu mudo aqui, só quero apenas salvar os dados do meu usuário após o login e exibir quando precisar.

Answer (score 2):

Tem duas opções que seria: 
-usar $rootScope -> http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope 
-usar services -> http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Recomendo usar o service pois existe problemas envolvendo variáveis globais.

Um exemplo de services:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.factory('Usuario', function() {
  return {
    first_name : 'anonymous'
  };
});
```

Setar valores:

```
Usuario.first_name = 'Nome aqui';
```

Usar no controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, Usuario) {
   $scope.nome = Usuario.first_name;
}
```